# Is template for angular 4 is available for visual studio 2015?

Tags: angular, templates, visual-studio-2015

Hi all i am new to angular 2, i am learning. and today got to know angular 4 already came. Is there any angular 4 template for visual studio 2015 like angular 2?  or any way to update scripts to angular 4?

Comment: No angular 4 template available..any one knows?